# Line drawn with double distance flickers/disappears in PDF when zooming

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following, very basic code to draw a double line in tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [double distance=0.5cm] (0,0)--(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line ist drawn correctly, however in the generated PDF, it is flickering when I zoom out. Even worse, the lines disappear completely at some zoom levels: At zoom level 100%, I see both lines as desired. At zoom level 125%, only one line is visible. At zoom level 50%, none of the two lines are visible.

This is very strange behavior, because if I just draw a single line, it is perfectly visible at all zoom levels.

This is really a problem, because some of my drawings can only be understand if all lines are visible.

Is there any solution to this problem?

EDIT: I use Adobe Acrobat Reader and the internal PDF viewer of Texmaker. The problem exists in both.

This code generates basically the same output by drawing the two lines manually, but doesn't have the described problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(5,0);
\draw (0,0.5cm)--(5,0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I want to use the double distance option as it greatly simplifies certain things... For me it seems the double distance option is broken?

Comment: Which PDF viewer? Have you tried a different PDF viewer? This sound a lot as a (lack of) antialiasing...

Comment: This depends on the browser and is independent of (La)TeX.

Comment: The thing is, it works perfectly fine for normal lines, so it *should* also work here, right? If I draw two lines manually it looks as expected even when zooming, but that cannot be the solution?

Comment: @SampleTime It works for normal lines because they are normal lines while a double line is a very thick black line with a smaller white lines drawn in the middle. Things like "thin line optimization" etc will behave very differently for both methods.

Comment: @samcarter Ok, didn't know that... do you probably know any replacement/library that draws double lines/arrows without drawing a white line above a thick black line but drawing actual lines?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAroa.png Do you have "enhance thin lines" activated?

Comment: @samcarter Yes, I have that option activated, the problem persits unfortunatly.

Comment: @SampleTime Try without this option.

Comment: @samcarter Good point. Didn't know/consider that about `double` lines in `tikz`. Would you mind if I add this to my question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Please go ahead and add it. (maybe improve the black/white description with line colour and background colour ...)

Comment: @SampleTime And I am afraid I don't know any other libraries to draw double lines, but I am no tikz expert. My usual approach with tikz: add a funny duck and nobody will care if the lines flicker :) This and not using Adobe reader.

Comment: @samcarter I tried it without the option but the problem is still there. It flickers "differently", but still flickers. Also, without that options thin lines look generally poor, so I would not like to rely on that...

Comment: @SampleTime Then the best advice I can offer: don't use adobe reader.

Comment: Well, thats not really an option because I want other people to be able to read the document without inconvenience and Adobe reader is very widespread... but thanks for the explanation, I hope there is somewhere a nice solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

> Summary
>
> - A line is drawn as a line. A double line is drawn as a thick line (black, lien color) with a thinner line in the middle with another color (white in your); thanks to user **samcarter** for this information.
> - Actual thin lines are subject to the so-called [Spatial anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing).
> - In Adobe viewers there is an option to "enhance thin lines".

Here is an animation in Adobe Acrobat X Pro:

[image]

I assume that the main problem is due to the fact that the line has a line width (height) that is not an integer of pixels on the screen (e. g. 2 px vs. 2.6543 px).

Therefore the viewer has to compensate: [Spatial anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) on Wikipedia

When you activate/deactivate the option (`Ctrl + K` on my system) *make thin lines more visible* (or similar, I have the German version), then this sometimes helps.

The answer assumes that you use an Adobe viewer.

[image]

### Update after Update of the Question

I propose that you make the line widths the same in both examples before you test your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [double distance=0.5cm, line width = 0.5pt] (0,0)--(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 0.5pt] (0,0)--(5,0);
\draw[line width = 0.5pt] (0,0.5cm)--(5,0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both examples look pretty similarly on my system.

[image]

Comment: I tried that option, unfortunatly the problem persists... also, why does the problem disapear if I draw the lines manually although the same output is generated?

Comment: @SampleTime Yes, I also tested it. The option has an effect but not necessarily an improvement :). I am afraid that you have to live with it. Maybe **try a thicker line width**.

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunatly the problem still persists... only the manually drawn lines are rendered correctly.

Comment: @SampleTime Yes. I think that **samcarter**s point is the key to the explanation (not the solution).