# Text above tikz arrow -- success depends on the length of the text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I've tried to position a single letter above an arrow using tikz. But it seems only to work for longer texts. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
%   \tikz\draw[-implies,double equal sign distance] %<- works fine
%       (0,0) -- node [above] {help} (1,0);

    \tikz\draw[-implies,double equal sign distance] %<- doesn't work (lines are strange/missing)
        (0,0) -- node [above] {hell} (1,0);
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your problem. Both examples in your MWE work fine for me. Also, if I add athird example that only contains a single letter instead of a word: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL7RP.png Could you please add a screenshot of the output you get?

Comment: @leandriis damn, tried to make screenshots and discovered it was a pdf-viewer-problem (resolution to small) So I'll delete this question in round about five minutes (or earlier if you reply before)

Comment: I would not delete the question as it might help future users with the same problem. Maybe we can find a duplicate that already has an answer and close your question as duplicate instead.

Comment: [Line drawn with double distance flickers/disappears in PDF when zooming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419847/134144)  deals with a similar problem.